# Email signature in gmail showing images as attachments

Tags: html-email

We've built a custom HTML email which will be used as an email signature for Office 365 accounts. During testing we notice that when the signature is sent to a Gmail account, Gmail shows 2 of the 9 images as attachments. To test I copy the contents of the HTML file and paste it into a new email. Sending it to another Outlook email works perfectly fine too.

An example of the code which wraps an image that displays as an attachment:

```
<table style="width: 480px; font-size: 9pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height:14px; " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:125px; vertical-align: middle" valign="middle" align="center">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.co.uk">
                <img border="0" width="88" height="88" style="width:88px; height:88px; border:0;" src="http://an-example-image.png" alt="Example logo"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The images are being served from an S3 bucket over https.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update:** Making the images as .JPG has fixed one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that any image over `15KB` will display as an attachment for Gmail. Reducing the file size to below has solved the issue for us.

Comment: Not true! My image is just about `2.8 KB`, but still it shows as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Unless those two images are not shown in the email at all, this is not something you can fix on Gmail.
I may have a workaround, which is offering your images via a http**s** link. This somewhat fixes the issue.

Comment: The images do still appear in Gmail. I forgot to add, I'll amend my question, but the images are served from S3 using https as well.